# Android Circular Timer

Tags: android, android-animation, android-progressbar

I want to create a timer that will fill a circle with a certain animation (the ring fills in with a specific color). The effect I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Can someone tell me how can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating custom components, please check [Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). Excerpt for Basic Approach:

> 1. Extend an existing View class or subclass with your own class.
> 2. Override some of the methods from the superclass. The superclass methods to override start with 'on', for example, onDraw(),
>      onMeasure(), and onKeyDown(). This is similar to the on... events in
>      Activity or ListActivity that you override for lifecycle and other
>      functionality hooks.
> 3. Use your new extension class. Once completed, your new extension class can be used in place of the view upon which it was based.

**For create circular progress bar,**

check custom library at https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar, this should get you started.

Some related SO links,

[Android Countdown Timer Circular Progress Bar doesn't match with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631817/android-countdown-timer-circular-progress-bar-doesnt-match-with-timer)