# Error in MediaPlayer : E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19) - Android

Tags: java, android, media-player

I know that there is some similar questions, but none of them answered my question. When I Click a button, media player is called, and this is appearing in the log.

```
06-02 00:20:38.980 26035-26035/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
06-02 00:20:39.019 26035-26035/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-02 00:20:39.026 26035-26035/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
```

After some time, this message above is substituted by this bellow, and the sound provided by the media player does not play anymore.

```
06-02 00:23:21.032 28749-28749/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
06-02 00:23:21.076 28749-28749/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-02 00:23:21.090 28749-28749/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-02 00:23:21.396 28749-28772/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
06-02 00:23:21.396 28749-28749/myapp.com.facadezpontos E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

this is the code for the MediaPlayer

```
public void buttonClick(Context context, MediaPlayer mp){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bubble_nice);
        mp.start();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)

Comment: this question does not solve the problem

Comment: @Felipe Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @SagarHudge yes, I posted the answer bellow. I hope it helps you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem!

I changed the way I call the sound file, here's how I did it.

I put the file inside the assets in order to make it works.

```
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {  
        mp.stop();
    } 

    try {
        mp.reset();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got this from here: [android - how to make a button click play a sound file every time it been pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464782/android-how-to-make-a-button-click-play-a-sound-file-every-time-it-been-presse)