# How can we fix this error? java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

How should we go about fixing this code. We've spent the past 24 hours straight trying to get audio to save in Android

Our tired eyes would much appreciate the help!

We're trying to create an audio analysis app which analyses a microphone input

```
package com.example.opus2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;



public class audioTest extends MainActivity{

    public int saveMarker=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.save_test);
    }


    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.saveBttn: {

                Button saveButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBttn);
                if(saveMarker==0){
                    TextView done = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text);
                    done.setText("Done2");
                    saveButton.setText("Saved?");
                    saveMarker=1;
                    String save_file = "viola";
                    try {
                        recordAudio(save_file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                }
                else{
                    saveButton.setText("Save");
                    saveMarker=0;

                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void recordAudio(String fileName) throws IOException {
        TextView done = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text);
        done.setText("Done1");

        final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, fileName);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sound/" + fileName+".mp4");

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(audioTest.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(R.string.lbl_recording);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setButton("Stop recording", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }
        });

        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface p1) {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.show();
        */

        recorder.start();
        done = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text);
        done.setText("Done");
        }
}
```

----ERRORS------

```
11-02 22:29:18.416    3256-3256/com.example.opus2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
            at com.example.opus2.audioTest.recordAudio(audioTest.java:96)
            at com.example.opus2.audioTest.onClick(audioTest.java:40)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post the exception ?

Comment: can you please post the logcat stack trace

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: Could you remove the `{}` in the case in the switch `case R.id.saveBttn: {`

Comment: I thought something looked weird there. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: just wonder if it's something to do with the graph here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816551/java-lang-illegalstateexception-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the state of your Media Recorder if it actually is prepared. If not: wait for some milliseconds until it is prepared before calling the start record.

Also check the reference on android developers for more information on the different recorder states:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: you've led me to notice that mediarecorder doesnt work on the emulator. But sadly that hasnt solved it